# reading excel data by column using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have never read from an excel file in VB.NET before so sorry if anything is off.

I am downloading an .csv file from a vendors ftp service that has 8 columns 
( style # - mfr.item # - description - metal type - availability - center weight - total weight - retail value )

I am trying to retrieve all data in the rows bellow style # and retail value
there are roughly 4,649 rows

I am not sure how to do this.

I load the excel file using the microsoft.office.interop.excel:

```
Dim eApp As excel.Application
Dim eBook As excel.Workbook
Dim eSheet As excel.Worksheet
Dim eCell As excel.Range

eApp = New excel.Application
eBook = eApp.Workbooks.Open(localFile)
eSheet = eBook.Worksheets(1)
eCell = eSheet.UsedRange
```

Can anyone help me on what I need to do next? I have browsed google for a few hours now and have not gotten anything to work, just return an object name.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are so almost there! Here are two ways.

Way #1: Add the following, after the `eCell = eSheet.UsedRange`:

```
Dim eCellArray as System.Array = eCell.Value
```

Then get the values via `eCellArray(r,c)`, where r is the row and c is the column (each starting from 1).

Way #2: Use this expression to get the value of a cell:

```
CType(eCell(r,c),Excel.Range).Value ' For Option Strict, or just to get IntelliSense to work.
```

or simply

```
eCell(r,c).Value
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, access the cells in a range like this:

```
Dim iRow as Integer = 1
Dim iCol as Integer
Dim rng as Excel.Range = getYourRangeFromSomewhere()
Dim rngCell as Excel.Range

For iCol = 1 To 10 
   rngCell = rng.Cells(iRow,iCol)
   Debug.Print rngCell.Value
Next
```

Comment: No, an excel range is basically a two dimensional array. Not something structured like a table in a database.