# VB.NET 2008: Import CSV & Extract Only Certain Named Columns

Tags: vb.net, csv, import, export

I'm using VB.NET 2008 and what I'm trying to do is very simple, yet I can't seem to figure it out.

I have an CSV file with around 200 columns and 50,000 rows that has the column headers in the first row.  I need to read this file and export three named columns (Sample ID No, Analysis Date, P Count) to a tab delimited .TXT file.  The columns may be in different orders depending on the machine that creates the original CSV, so I definitely need it to be exported by named column.

I can do this all day in console C with my eyes closed; however, my boss knows that I'm leaving in a few months and is asking that I do this in VB.NET so another guy can make tweaks in the future.   I've spent several days looking through this site and others trying to find a solution.  I've managed to get the CSV into a DataGridView (albeit without column headers, ugh), but I can't figure out how to get a data out of these.   I'm just not used to this OOP stuff to be honest.    If anyone would be willing to assist with this or even steer me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Search for VB.Net OleDB CSV for one way to go. I use Kellerman Software's CSV library http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-50-csv-reports.aspx for some projects.

Comment: This is a real good starting place: [Read Excel from VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666425/reading-excel-data-by-column-using-vb-net)

Comment: Yu might want to start a new post and provide some sample code you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not free, but almost ($5, free trail) - I user Kellerman Software's .Net CSV Reports.

Sample downloading a CSV from the web, works for local files to:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Using client As New WebClient ' Imports System.Net needed
        ' Download the web page as a string.
        Dim value As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.jotform.com/csv/@#&*2131238*((")
        Dim rdr As New CsvReader ' Imports KellermanSoftware.CsvReports needed
        Dim dt As DataTable = rdr.CsvStringToDataTable(value)
        dgv1.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Sub
```

Once the data is in a DataTable you'll have the named columns assuming the source has headers.

---

Note that this is licensed software and would require an included dll - I'm sure there are open source versions out there somewhere. I use this type of software for short term tasks, not great for production unless you buy the source and compile it in.